# django-extensions: Run a script using runscript which is inside a folder within scripts

Tags: python, django, run-script, django-extensions

I am getting problems running a script that is inside a folder inside of scripts folder using runscript command included in django-extensions.

The folder structure in my project is like:

```
-apps
-scripts
    -syllabus
        -first.py
    -second.py
```

The files first.py and second.py are identical.

It has a run function as required by the django-extension runscript command.

```
def run(*args):
    # my function call for the script.
```

I have well placed **init**.py and I can run second.py from the command:

`./manage.py runscript second --script-args=excel.xlsx`

But somehow I cannot run the first.py file from the runscript command. With this command:

`./manage.py runscript first --script-args=excel.xlsx`

I get

`No (valid) module for script 'first' found
Try running with a higher verbosity level like: -v2 or -v3`

I even tried running with higher verbosity level adding `-v2` and `-v3` at the end. But got this error:

`No (valid) module for script 'first' found`

I know that I am missing something simple, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to run the script as follows:

```
/manage.py runscript scripts.syllabus.first --script-args=excel.xlsx
```

Here scripts and syllabus are two directories containing `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 2):

I dont have any experience with django. But the problem can be solved by adding `syllabus` to module lookup path. To do that add the following code in the `__init__.py` file under `scripts` directory.

```
import sys
import os

curr_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, curr_path + '/syllabus')
```

Or another way is to tell python that `syllabus` is a module itself. In that case you just need to rename `first.py` to `__init__.py`. You will then have to invoke it as

```
./manage.py runscript syllabus --script-args=excel.xlsx
```

Comment: The first solution didn't work. But the second one worked. The problem I have with the second solution is that I have multiple scripts inside the syllabus folder. So, I need to change something for each time that I run the script.